# Stop systemd from reading partitions

Tags: hard-drive, systemd, partitioning, udev

I'm trying to do a data recovery job on a hard drive (using `ddrescue` and some custom scripts) but every time I insert the drive, `dmesg` records multiple read errors to all seven of the drive's partitions; These reads bog down the drive and it fails (requiring a power cycle) before I can get much data off of it.

I've tried tracking down what is doing the disk access and it seems like it's `systemd-u` (that's what `lsof` shows).

Is there any way to stop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `systemd-u` is an alias for `systemd-udevd.service`. This can be stopped using:

`systemctl stop systemd-udevd.service`

However, it seems like the service is restarted automatically by `systemd-udevd-control.socket` and `systemd-udevd-kernel.socket`. When I stopped those two using `systemctl` the problem was resolved. When finished imaging the disk, it's probably a good idea to restart the services.